# Not getting user email address in inquiry from Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, email, web-applications, phpmailer

I am stuck into a small issue. When a user sends an inquiry from laravel website, I get to see fixed email address in the from section. Is there any way out to make it dynamic. I want to see user's email address in the inbox.

Here's my .env code:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=admin@mywebsite.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=12345
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

When I reply the same email back, I can see the user's email in reply to field.

Please let know, where should I make changes. Also let me know if you require detail view into other code.

Comment: Can you add your code written for sending email ?

Comment: You have to make changes in your code and need to add 'from' attribute of Mailer. For that please show us what code you have written so far to send  a mail Because there are several ways to send a mail in Laravel

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you should not try to spoof the email coming from the user. This can lead to issues like your email provider flagging the message as spam and possibly your webhost getting flagged as a spammer. The better practice is to have your email delivered from your admin@mywebsite.com account as you currently do and then set the reply-to as it sounds like the app is already doing.